# NSTableView selection & highlights

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a NSTableView as a very central part of my Application and want it to integrate more with the rest of it. It has only one column (it's a list) and I draw all Cells (normal NSTextFieldCells) myself.

The first problem is the highlighting. I draw the highlight myself and want to get rid of the blue background. I now fill the whole cell with the original background color to hide the blue background, but this looks bad when dragging the cell around. I tried overriding `highlight:withFrame:inView:` and `highlightColorWithFrame:inView:` of NSCell but nothing happened. How can I disable automatic highlighting?

I also want all rows/cells to be deselected when I click somewhere outside my NSTableView. Since the background / highlight of the selected cell turns gray there must be an event for this, but I can't find it. I let my cells expand on a double click and may need to undo this. So getting rid of the gray highlight is not enough.

**EDIT:** I add a subview to the NSTableView when a cell gets double clicked and then `resignFirstResponder` of the NSTableView gets called. I tried this:

```
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    if (![[self subviews] containsObject:[[self window] firstResponder]])
    {
        [self deselectAll:self];
        ...
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Besides that it's not working I would need to implement this method for all objects in the view hierarchy. Is there an other solution to find out when the first responder leaves a certain view hierarchy?

Comment: Use setAction: method of NSOutlineView. Have a look at [this][1] answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23337627/944634

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to achieve a similar solution (with an NSOutlineView but this has no difference): when clicking inside the outline view BUT not in a row with a cell (for instance at the empty bottom of a source list), I wanted the currently selected row to be deselected. I ended up with this little piece of code that might be of some help.

In a NSOutlineView subclass, I've put:

```
@implementation ClickOutlineView

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint pointInWindow = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSPoint pointInOutlineView = [self convertPoint:pointInWindow toView:nil];

    int rowIndex = [self rowAtPoint:pointInOutlineView];

    if ([theEvent clickCount] == 1 && rowIndex == -1) {
        [self deselectAll:nil];
    }
    else {
        [super mouseDown:theEvent];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

No doubt it's too late to help the question's poster, but this may help others who come across this on Google (as I did).

You can prevent row selection by selecting 'None' in the 'Highlight' drop-down menu, in the attributes inspector in Xcode 4.

There is also an answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063218/nstableview-disble-highlight-color) for setting this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading `-highlight:withFrame:inView:` should be correct. How did you do the overload? Does an `NSLog()` statement indicate that your code is running? You should also look at NSTableView's `-highlightSelectionInClipRect:`, which may be more convenient for this.

In order to do something (such as unselect the current selection) when the user clicks outside the table view, overload `-resignFirstResponder` on NSTableView.

Comment: I put ´highlight:withFrame:inView:´ in my NSTextField subclass and it was never called. But overriding ´highlightSelectionInClipRect:´ did the trick, thanks!

I thought of ´resignFirstResponder´, but unfortunately I add a subview to the NSTableView so the user can edit the cells content. Is there an other way?

Comment: Are you using the normal field editor for your editing? Does NSTableView's resignFirstResponder not get called when you click outside of it (even with this subview)?

Comment: No, I created my own, more complex view for editing the selected object. `resignFirstResponder` gets called, but it also gets called when the editing view becomes first responder and you can see my attempt to "oversee" this event above.

Comment: If your special editor is a subclass of NSTextField, then you can let NSTableView manage it by overloading NSTableView's -currentEditor. That way, you don't add a new view; you let NSTableView's built-in field editor system work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. It's a NSView with lot's of things like subviews, PopUpButtons etc. =/

Comment: Sorry, I said NSTextField, I meant NSText (or NSTextView). I'd still take a look at how custom field editors work. You may get a lot of help from working yourself into the system. http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html