# Disable highlight color NSTableview - Apple Development

Tags: cocoa, tracking, nstableview

I am developing an application in cocoa which needs to select an item by clicking a check box inside a NSTableview.I need to select the cell without highlighting the row of table view
Is it possible to do this... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the cell highlight color of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787093/remove-the-cell-highlight-color-of-uitableview)

Comment: exact dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62795221/294884

Answer (score 20):

`NSTableView` has a method called `setSelectionHighlightStyle:` to which you can send `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone` as an option and it will not show a highlight.

So, in `awakeFromNib:` or similar:

`[tableView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];`

Comment: Or in the Interface Builder, table attributes inspector, set "Highlight" to "None".

Answer (score 2):

Normally, only selectable or selected cells can be tracked; checkboxes need tracking in order to be checked/unchecked.

But it may be possible to do what you want by using the [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s delegate: the [`tableView:shouldTrackCell:forTableColumn:row:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method can be used to allow the tracking of non-selectable or non-selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the relevant Boolean property in the underlying model? If you're using Bindings, the table view should pick up the change automatically; if not, you can tell the table view to reload that row.

Answer (score 0):

NSTableview Has method to set selection HighlightStyle

Add below line in your tableivew method :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
{ 
    let cell:customCell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: 
     "customCell", owner: self) as! customCell

      tableview.selectionHighlightStyle = .none
}
```

Comment: Before providing your own answer, especially to a somewhat old question, read the existing answers. If your answer is not materially different from others, making a new answer should be avoided. Instead, if you have additional data worth sharing (such as swift details), edit the answer that already exists and is most like yours.

Comment: this is 100% incorrect, as explained at length here .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62795221/294884