# Remove the cell highlight color of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to remove the default blue color of uitableview cell selection. I don't want any selection color there. I have not created a custom cell class. I'm customizing the cell by adding labels and buttons over it. 
I tried doing:

```
cell.selectioncolor = [UIColor clearcolor];
```

but it says that this method is deprecated.

Comment: If you google here, be aware that the extremely old (10 years plus) selected answer here, is simply wrong.

Comment: If you google here, be aware that the above comment is not true.

Comment: LOL man :)  you know I think there is some mass confusion on this QA between the various types of "selection / clicking / etc" (certainly, it may be me confused)

Answer (score 417, accepted):

In Swift:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
```

or simply:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Comment: I kept that code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, is that the exact place to keep?

Comment: @Pawriwes, yes. If I remember correctly you can also set that property in cell's XIB if you create your cell using Interface Builder

Comment: If I do so, when editing, it do not select the cell :(

Comment: This answer is basically wrong. You do it in the cell subclass. You would never do it in the VC once it has been built.

Comment: Answer by @Fattie deserves more recognition. If you place that `cell.selectionStyle = .none` code in VC, you'll see the default color show up when you select the cell. You must put that line in your cell subclass if what you want is your custom color showing up.

Comment: Right, it's not that "I'm so smart". There are a number of answers on SO that are famously "plain out of date".  This answer is **out of date by literally a decade (!)**  Every single person who googles here and glances at that answer - is getting totally wrong information.  Note too that in certain circumstances, it will actually crash if you do it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 74):

In the `Storyboard` or `XIB` Attributes Inspector, set `Selection` to `None`.

---

[image: Selection: None]

Comment: additional, you have to check "Table View **Cell**" if you change in "table view" than you don't select cells.

Comment: @Pulkit that is not true. This will only disable the selection state of the cell. This has nothing to do with the data being displayed in it or handling it's interaction.

Check to make sure you are have all proper registration set and aren't overriding other functions.

Comment: ensure you do this for the cell and not the tableview

Answer (score 15):

Objective-C:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

// or 

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Swift 3+:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;

// or

cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Swift 2:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

If you want to change it just using Interface Builder Storyboard/Xib, select the cell that you want to remove the "Selection Style Effect" and define it as "None". It'll work like magic as well :D

[image: Storyboard / Xib]

Comment: Swift 4 : cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3.0

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 11):

```
// Swift 2.0

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Comment: Or you can use the enum value directly                                  cell.selectionStyle = .None

Answer (score 8):

### Do note that every answer which mentions "selectionStyle" is completely wrong.

`selectionStyle` determines ***whether or not you can click on the cell***.

It has nothing to do with whether the cell is turned "gray" when you click on it.

The only way to turn off the "gray effect" (when you click on it) is like this:

```
class YourCell:  UITableViewCell {
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        selectedBackgroundView?.isHidden = true
    }

    ...
}
```

### Note that `selectedBackgroundView` is indeed available on the storyboard.

I wouldn't fool with it because the lifecycle is so strange, but note that these days, indeed you can get at `selectedBackgroundView` on the storyboard. It's possible you could handle it in there.

### The answer by @fingia, see below.

Regarding the question on this page, how to "remove the cell highlight color", notice that the @fingiua answer correctly states that you adjust `selectedBackgroundView`. However, it states that what you do is change the background color.

This *used to work in the past* to some extent and is still possible in *certain situations* but it's a hell of a task figuring out when in the lifecycle you have to set the color - because, UIKit itself is constantly setting the color! (For example, if you do it in the obvious didMoveToSuperview or prepareForReuse ... it simply doesn't work.)

This is a great example of how, on the internet, for obscure yet critical issues, **there is often a lot of VERY OLD example code on the internet, which gets copied endlessly, which is either just wrong or "half wrong", but still gets copied endlessly**.

There's no reason at all you'd fool with the color, because what you want to do is simply ... hide it.  So just hide it.  This (of course) works reliably (indeed, you can do so anywhere at all in the view cycle, once it's hidden that's the end of it).

Comment: Check documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623221-selectionstyle - it specifically says that property controls only cell presentation (i.e. background view) on selection and does not affect how cell responds to the selection

Comment: Sorry @Fattie but your assertion is the one that is incorrect here. You can set `selectionStyle` to `.none` and still select the row. The currently highest voted and selected answer is not technically wrong. Please read the documentation for `UITableViewCell selectionStyle` and `UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle`. Your updated answer here is no better than setting `selectionStyle` to `.none`. It only hides the selection, it doesn't prevent the selection.

Comment: While I don't understand why 10 answers are needed to state that you can use `selectionStyle`, if someone actually wants to prevent cell selection, the correct solution is to return `nil` from the `willSelectRowAt` delegate method.

Comment: hi @HangarRash . Regarding your first comment. You may have totally misread the question. Here's the question: **Remove the cell highlight color**  the OP is not saying anything about *whether or not you can select a row in general* (which is what the `selectionStyle` property affects) nor does it say anything about *whether you can select specific rows* (you achieve that with the technique mentioned in your second comment).

Comment: hi @Vladimir - please read the question title

Comment: @Fattie Your updated answer states: *"selectionStyle determines whether or not you can click on the cell."* - this is not true at all. If you set `selectionStyle = .none`, the `didSelectRowAt` delegate method is still called. You state *"It has nothing to do with whether the cell is turned "gray" when you click on it."* - this is not true at all. Using `selectionStyle = .none` does one thing and one thing only - it prevents the cell from changing color when it is selected.

Comment: @Fattie BTW - did you test your updated answer? It doesn't work. I still see the gray cell selection when tapping on a row in the table view. I'm using your exact custom cell class. From the docs for `selectedBackgroundView`: *"UITableViewCell adds the value of this property as a subview only when the cell has a selected state."* - so at the time you are trying to set `isHidden = true`, `selectedBackgroundView` is `nil` so nothing changes.

Comment: @HangarRash - your second point, yes I use it widely in production code; it works (for us!) but definitely anything is possible, I will review what you have said and revert ...

Comment: re your penultimate comment: what you say is the exact opposite of my experience - !  I will carefully check it out.  Perhaps there is some issue with storyboard settings, or the place in the view cycle where one applies it.  @HangarRash

Answer (score 7):

Setting the TableView Selection style to `.none` was affecting the responsiveness and performance of the tableview in my app (`didSelectRowAt indexPath` taps were getting delayed). My solution to this problem was to hide the selected background view on `awakeFromNib()` when the cell is first created:

`selectedBackgroundView?.isHidden = true`

Answer (score 4):

Try this for swift

```
cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Answer (score 3):

right answer should be:

`cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = <choose your color>`

The selection type is a different property that when set to `.none` produces what you want PLUS other unwanted side-effects.

If you do not want the cell to be *highlighted*, then make its background view's color the same as when it is *not* highlighted.

Comment: fingia, this is no longer exactly correct.  you simply set it once to "isHidden" and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5.4 , just put the `selectionStyle = .none`

Example:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    selectionStyle = .none 

}
```

Comment: working for me.......

Comment: easypeasy. Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong.  https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/ca64e1dc4fa41adfc603 .  The correct approach if you're changing a style is the one in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    return cell
}
```